# Why doesn't a SVG rect element apply width/height when referenced via link element?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to get `<use>` elements to reference elements from within a `<defs>` element but changing their size. Specifically I'm trying to reference a `<rect>` element and setting/changing the `width` and `height` attributes, but it doesn't render the elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <rect id="square-1" width="100" height="100" fill="tomato" />
        <rect id="square-2" fill="lime" />
    </defs>

    <use xlink:href="#square-1" />
    <use xlink:href="#square-2" width="50" height="50" x="25" y="25"/>
</svg>
```

`#square-2` won't be rendered at all, because `width` and `height` have no effect.

Works: http://jsfiddle.net/Thasmo/gue0km6z/2/
Doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/Thasmo/gue0km6z/1/

Why isn't it possible to set/override `width` and `height` for the referenced `<rect>` element?

Comment: because the specification says so: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement

Answer (score 0):

elements referenced by "use" only inherit style-propertys (everything you can also write as style="..." f.e. fill, stroke etc.).
Transforms do work, but the best way to do it is by using symbols:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1">
 <defs>
  <rect id="square-1" width="100" height="100" fill="tomato" />
        <symbol id="square-2" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <rect fill="lime" width="100" height="100"/>
        </symbol>
 </defs>

 <use xlink:href="#square-1" />
 <use xlink:href="#square-2" width="50" height="50" x="25" y="25"/>
</svg>
```